# How to config geth node to get ERC-20 tokens balances

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20, json-rpc, python

I'm trying to tune my geth node to get ERC-20 tokens balances, but y API call always returns

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': '0x'}
```

My geth node version:

```
instance=Geth/v1.9.13-stable-cbc4ac26/windows-amd64/go1.14.2
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

I have fully synced node (200Gb size)

I've tried to connect my node from MyCrypto wallet. It works well (main balance), but I can't get token balances via my geth node.

Also i've tried to use python pyetherbalance module.

```
import pyetherbalance
ethbalance = pyetherbalance.PyEtherBalance(infura_url)
balance_omg = ethbalance.get_token_balance('USDT', ethereum_address)
```

eth_call retruns always {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': '0x'} if I connecting to my geth node, but it work well with infura node

eth.blockNumber = 10040830

Command line:

```
geth - -rpc - -rpcapi "db, txpool, ethash, eth,net,web3,personal" - -rpcaddr = "127.0.0.1" - -rpcport = "8545" - -rpccorsdomain = "*"
```

Api python code:

```
address = "0x......"
contract_address = "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7" # USDT
abi = '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000' + address[2:]
params = [{"to": contract_address, "data": abi}, "latest"]
response = json_rpc_post('eth_call', params, 1)
```

Comment: If you query most recent `eth.blockNumber` what does it return? What command line do you use to launch geth? What code do you use to query balances?

Comment: eth.blockNumber = 10040830
<br/>
geth - -rpc - -rpcapi "db, txpool, ethash, eth,net,web3,personal" - -rpcaddr = "127.0.0.1" - -rpcport = "8545" - -rpccorsdomain = "*"
console


I've tryed to use my node from MyCrypto wallet with no luck. Get token balances has no result.

Comment: Also i've used python module pyetherbalance wich has such code:

    address = "0x......"
    contract_address = "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7" # USDT
    abi = '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000' + address[2:]
    params = [{"to": contract_address, "data": abi}, "latest"]
    response = json_rpc_post('eth_call', params, 1)

if I use my node, I have response {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': '0x'}
if I use infura node, the result is success and balance is returned